# Argument deduction for template member functions does not work for classes declared inside function?

Tags: c++, templates

```
struct Test
{
        template <class T>
        void print(T& t)
    {
        t.print();
    }
};

struct A
{
    void print() {printf( "A");}
};

struct B
{
    void print() {printf( "B");}
};

void test_it()
{   
    A a;
    B b;

    Test t;
    t.print(a);
    t.print(b);
}
```

This compiles fine.

```
struct Test
{
        template <class T>
        void print(T& t)
    {
        t.print();
    }
};


void test_it()
{   
    struct A
    {
        void print() {printf( "A");}
    };

    struct B
    {
        void print() {printf( "B");}
    };

    A a;
    B b;

    Test t;
    t.print(a);
    t.print(b);
}
```

This fails with error :
no matching function for call to 'Test::print(test_it()::A&)'

Can anyone explain me why this happen ?
Thanks!!!

Comment: not 100% sure, but might be because Test is in the global scope an hence cannot possibly 'see' A and B which are function local

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your second example, `A` and `B` are local types, which can't be used as template type arguments in C++03 as per *§14.3.1/2*:

> A local type, a type with no linkage, an unnamed type or a type compounded from any of these types shall not be used as a template-argument for a template type-parameter.

Comment: @Alexander K.: Note that C++0x lifts this restriction. `gcc-4.6.0 -std=c++0x` compiles the second example just fine.